# Afraid to upgrade

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, pinning

I need to know how I can avoid the Nvidia driver update. Last time I updated I fell victim to the Login Loop Lunacy. I had to do a complete reinstall of Ubuntu to get control back of my MacBook Pro 17" after trying everything else. Now that I have my Ubuntu running again I really want to update but I do not want the Nvidia Login Loop issues I had before. How can I avoid updating the Nvidia drivers?
BTW..I am pretty much a newbie to Linux...so bear that in mind! Thanx!

Comment: Generally, it's recommended to uninstall graphics drivers and all other third party PPA's prior to doing the update.  Granted the computer runs slowly without the GPU, but slow is better then not running at all.  After upgrade, the Nvidia cna be re-installed, but as I don't use one, I have no experience to impart.

Comment: Do you have recent, valid backups of your data?

Comment: If the answer is no to the backups question, do one now.